# iTunes Search API での大量データ取得について

Tags: api, app-store

iTunesのsearch APIでアプリを取得したいのですが、 
120万件のアプリがあるようなのですが、 
仮にAPIで50件習得できたとしても2万4千回以上叩く必要があります。 
それで、質問なのですが以下の2点大丈夫でしょうか？

1、連続して2万4千回APIを叩いても大丈夫か？（レートリミットなど）

2、法的な問題などにならないか？

以上教えていただきたいです。

Comment: 2件の回答ありがとうございます。
他の回答を待ちながら、Enterprise Partner Feed を調べてみることにします。
有力な情報心から感謝申しあげます。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apple公式の以下のページを見る限りでは、具体的な制限の有無や内容については言及されていないようですね。

https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api/

ただ実際には、ある程度連続して呼び出したら403エラーが返るようになったという情報が英語版StackOverflowに寄せられています。

- [iTunes search JSON API returning 403 forbidden on server - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16957243/2818869)
- [iTunes Search API rate limit - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12596300/2818869)

> 120万件のアプリがあるようなのですが、仮にAPIで50件習得できたとしても2万4千回以上叩く必要があります。

全件取得したいようですが、冒頭の説明ページを見る限りでは `page` などのパラメータが存在せず、2ページ目以降を取得することはできないように思います。よって取得できるのは `limit` パラメータに指定できる最大値である200件が限度でしょう。

iTunes Storeの掲載データをまとめてダウンロードできる [Enterprise Partner Feed](https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-enterprise-partner-feed/) の利用を検討した方がいいかもしれません。（SearchAPIと異なり、申請が必要ですが）

Answer (score 1):

公式のドキュメントに記載はないようですが、offsetを指定できるので、全件取得はがんばればできそうですが、 ( https://syncer.jp/itunes-api-matome )
他の方が回答されているように、403の件もあるので、どうしてもAPIを使いたいなら一定時間あけたりなどの工夫と、かなり時間がかかることへの対応が必要でしょうね。